# GRAILS: how to get the number of currently signed in users via spring security core plugin?

Tags: session, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

my problem is, that i want to limit the number of users that can simultaneously be logged in  my application (this value is stored in the database). first i tried to do that with some configuration in tomcat or other web containers - but there´s the problem, that a session is used also if a user is not logged in (displaying the login page also needs a session in tomcat)... so i need to check how many users are "really" logged in.
i´ve found quite a lot code examples for the acegi plugin, but nothing really helpful about the springsecurity core plugin.

my snippets so far:

in resources.groovy i´ve defined my beans:

```
beans = {
    sessionRegistry(org.springframework.security.concurrent.SessionRegistryImpl)

    concurrentSessionController(org.springframework.security.concurrent.ConcurrentSessionControllerImpl) { 
        sessionRegistry = ref('sessionRegistry') 
        maximumSessions = -1 
   }
}
```

in BootStrap.groovy the begging of the init is :

```
class BootStrap {

    def springSecurityService

    def authenticationManager
    def concurrentSessionController
    def securityContextPersistenceFilter

    def init = { servletContext ->
        authenticationManager.sessionController = concurrentSessionController
        ...
```

and in Config.groovy i´ve added :

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.providerNames = ['concurrentSessionController', 'daoAuthenticationProvider', 'anonymousAuthenticationProvider', 'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider']
```

but then as soon as the application starts (grails run-app), it crashes, when it tries to configure the SpringSecury :

```
...
Running Grails application..

Configuring Spring Security ...
Application context shutting down...
Application context shutdown.
limepix@turbo:~/develop/testproject$
```

i have configured logging for my application - the content / the last entry in my logfile is:

```
2011-07-11 11:19:43,071 [main] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: No bean named 'concurrentSessionController' is defined
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'concurrentSessionController' is defined
        at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_createBeanList_closure22.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:648)
        at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.createBeanList(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:648)
        at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.this$2$createBeanList(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy)
        at SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure4.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:581)
        at org.grails.tomcat.TomcatServer.start(TomcatServer.groovy:212)
            at grails.web.container.EmbeddableServer$start.call(Unknown Source)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:158)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5_closure12.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.doCall(_GrailsSettings_groovy:280)
        at _GrailsSettings_groovy$_run_closure10.call(_GrailsSettings_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:149)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure5.call(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy:116)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy.this$4$runInline(_GrailsRun_groovy)
        at _GrailsRun_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsRun_groovy:59)
        at RunApp$_run_closure1.doCall(RunApp.groovy:33)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
        at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
        at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
```

maybe someone can point me to some docs, examples or can directly tell me, how to get the number of currently signed in users.

greeting from nuremberg, germany

limepix

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answer! Now i got it...

The steps i took are:

Defining the beans:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy 
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter 
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl 
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy

beans = { 

        sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl) 

        sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) { 
                maximumSessions = -1 
        } 

        concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){ 
                sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry 
                expiredUrl = '/login/concurrentSession' 
        } 
}
```

then in my controller i injected:

```
class SystemController {    

    def sessionRegistry
```

and the check, how many sessions are currently in use:

```
    def sessioncount = {
        def cnt = 0

        sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().each{
            cnt += sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(it, false).size()
        }    

        render cnt
    }
```

additional steps that must be made:

1. install templates from grails (grails install-templates)
2. add listener to web.xml:

   ```
   <listener>
       <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
   </listener>
   ```

and now it works!

great! :)

(now the next steps are - defining an eventlistener (when the user logs in) check the number of licenses(sessions) and permit or deny access to him. but i think that´s not that tricky... we´ll see...)

Comment: Why spring-security-core-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar? The plugin uses Spring Security 3.0; you shouldn't not mix in an incompatible jar file. Plus even if it were necessary it's much better to add dependencies in BuildConfig instead of the lib dir.

Comment: thanks burt, you´re right! i´ve found an example on nabble where a class was used, which i thought i would only find in an old version of spring security (btw. it worked...) - i didn´t looked deep enough. i removed the lib from my library dir and it still works ;)

Comment: btw. why isn´t there a possibility to get such information directly from the "springSecurityService" ? i think that such information could be used everywhere, where things like "floating licence" etc. come in question... (ala springSecurityService.getSessionsUsed() or springSecurityService.getNumUsersLoggedId() )

Comment: Were having errors because injected SessionRegistry was always with 0 sessions. We solved it by doing 'grails install-templates'. But be carefull! It will remove all custom configuration in web.xml

Answer (score 1):

First I was thinking of counting users which logged in given period, but this can be inaccurate.

I think you could cache user id and time of his last action. Then you could write filter, that on every action updates this cache if user is logged in. Then you could just count items that are in the cache. If your cache would be small, you could also iterate over it and remove users that are inactive for eg. five minutes (or any other, like session expiration - btw: `sessionId` could also be stored there, so you could check if that session is still valid). If cache big, scheduled job could take care of it.

Comment: hey. thanks for your answer! my first approach went nearly in the same direction, but then i asked myself - why implement some kind of "session control strategy" when it´s all already done ?! using the spring security plugin (and some additional libraries from spring) gives you all the possibilities to accomplish such tasks. (i´ve answered my own question with a little howto ;) )