# Testing if a user is logged in or no

Tags: grails, spring-security

How can I test if a user logged in or no using the spring security core plugin in grails?

I want to know for each user I have in my database if the user is online or no, 
I can’t figure out how to do this with the spring security plugin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648100/grails-how-to-get-the-number-of-currently-signed-in-users-via-spring-security-c

Comment: thanks Sergio, I have done like what is in that link, and now I have access to sessionRegistry, for what I need I think I have to use the method: getAllSessions (Object principal, boolean includeExpiredSessions), this let me Obtains all the known sessions for the specified principal, then I can know if the user have an active session or no, but one thing still not clear for me, what is the type of principal object for this method, 
I tried user Instance from my grails project but it doesn’t work

Comment: If you print instance.class you can see his type. Also you can see the type returned by the method.

Comment: The class type is : org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.springsecurity.GrailsUser , Now I must find out how to get a GrailsUser object corresponding to my User

Comment: How about User.get(grailsUser.username)

Comment: thank you again for your help sergio ,it finally worked with this :
`def userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.username)
  def sessionInfo = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(userDetails, true)`

Comment: Nice! Can you post your code as respose? I'm sure it will help others :-)

Answer (score 0):

The steps i took are:

Defining the beans:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy 
import org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter 
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl 
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy

beans = { 

        sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl) 

        sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) { 
                maximumSessions = -1 
        } 

        concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){ 
                sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry 
                expiredUrl = '/login/concurrentSession' 
        } 
}
```

install templates from grails (grails install-templates)

add listener to web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

injecting sessionRegistry in my service:

```
def sessionRegistry
```

...

```
def getSessionInformations(User user){
        def userDetails =   userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(user.username)
        def sessionInfo = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(userDetails, true)
        return sessionInfo
    }
```

.

```
def isOnline(User user) {
if (getSessionInformations(user)){return true } else { return false }
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. If a user loggs in and closes his browser the session remains open and your code would return that he is still logged in. I don't know if unused sessions are closed after a while a when. How do you solve this issue?

Comment: Hamila did you get this working ? If yes could you post your working code please ? Thanks ! Lorenzo