# Getting the number of currently logged in users from spring security core plugin in grails

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to get the number of currently logged in grails application. I'm using:
Grails 2.3.1 and spring-security-core:2.0-RC2 plugin.

By refering to this thread:
[GRAILS: how to get the number of currently signed in users via spring security core plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648100/grails-how-to-get-the-number-of-currently-signed-in-users-via-spring-security-c)

resources.groovy

```
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy

beans = {
    sessionRegistry(org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl)

    concurrencyFilter(org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter){
        sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
        expiredUrl = '/login/concurrentSession'
    }

    sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
        maximumSessions = -1
    }
}
```

I also modified web.xml and added:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

These are the only changes that I made to my application.

Modifying BootStrap in such fashion

```
class BootStrap {

    def springSecurityService

    def authenticationManager
    def concurrentSessionController
    def securityContextPersistenceFilter

    def init = { servletContext ->
        authenticationManager.sessionController = concurrentSessionController
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Causes error on start-up:

```
Error initializing the application: No such property: sessionController for class: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
Message: No such property: sessionController for class: org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager
```

The only think that I accomplished so far is that SessionRegistry is injected to my controller and I'm able to invoke

```
sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size()
```

without getting NullPointerException but it returns 0 no matter how many users are currently logged in.

I don't know where to proceed from here since I'm a beginner with spring.