# Howto ask spring security if specified user (not current) has valid session

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to request the plugin if a specified user (e.g. by id or username) is logged in or authenticated.

I only found to request this for the current user who send a request to my site. But I do't want this for the current user but for any user that I specify by id or username.

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6648100/grails-how-to-get-the-number-of-currently-signed-in-users-via-spring-security-c

Comment: Thank you for the hint! My problem is now the missing documentation or a howto. Now, I can get all sessions of a user that I have requested BUT the  lastRequestTime does not seem to be updated which is important for me. Also, how do I know what type of authentication (fully, remembered, anopnymously)?

Comment: You can easily achieve this with spring session managment, http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/session-mgmt.html and inject instance of SessionRegistry

Comment: Can you give me a hint how to do this in grails?